# Dummy debug class stuck on std::endl overload

Tags: c++, debugging, c++14, conditional-compilation

I thought I was going to do a quick-and-dirty `__DEBUG` enabled tracing with something like this:

```
#ifdef __DEBUG
#   define  dbg std::cout
#   define  err std::cerr
#else

#include <iostream>

class dummy_cout
{
private:

public:
    dummy_cout & operator << ( auto &obj )
    { return *this; }

    dummy_cout & operator << ( std::result_of< decltype( &std::endl ) >::type &obj )
    { return *this; }
};

#   define  dbg dummy_cout()
#   define  err dummy_cout()
#endif


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    dbg << "Bla, bla. bla..." << std::endl;
}
```

But it gives me:

```
cond_dbg.cpp:16:66: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  dummy_cout & operator << ( std::result_of< decltype( &std::endl ) >::type &obj )
```

I have also tried a half-dozen variations of `decltype`, `result_of`, `ostream`, etc. but I still haven't gotten any step further.

It oughta be simple. If I compile the code defining `__DEBUG`, I'd have `cout` and `cerr`. If I make a normal compilation, I'd have my `dummy_cout`, that simply does nothing but allows my code to compile without changes and little clutter.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A comment on your `operator <<` overload in `dummy_cout` class: That is just not how you overload C++ `std::ostream` insertion operators....

Comment: Why do you need to treat `std::endl` separately?  It should be captured by the templated version.

Comment: Thanks @Henri Menke. This was my very first trial but didn't work. `template argument deduction/substitution failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write `decltype(&std::endl)` because [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) isn't a function, it's a *function template*:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

As such, it doesn't have a type, so it doesn't make sense to ask for it. Moreover, even if it did have a type, the subsequent `result_of` wrapping wouldn't make any sense.

The reason that `std::cout << std::endl` works is that there is an [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that accepts a specific type of function pointer:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

This operator is not a function template (it is a member function of `basic_ostream`, which is a class template), and so overload resolution here triggers instantiation of a specialization of `endl`.

To get this to work, you should just do the same thing:

```
dummy_cout& operator<<( std::ostream&(*p)(std::ostream&) );
```

or pick some appropriate `CharT` and `Traits` for your dummy type:

```
dummy_cout& operator<<( std::basic_ostream<C,T>&(*p)(std::basic_ostream<C,T>& ) );
```

---

Just a note. This declaration is ill-formed any C++ standard:

```
dummy_cout& operator<<(auto& obj);
```

Terse function template syntax is a feature of the Concepts TS, which is still a TS. Unless you're using -`fconcepts`, you need to write:

```
template <class T>
dummy_cout& operator<<(T& obj);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you additionally point out the issue with the member function declaration: `dummy_cout& operator << ( auto &obj );`?.. Or is it now a legal declaration in C++XX?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Sure, added a note.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barry. `dummy_cout& operator<<( std::ostream&(*p)(std::ostream&) )` works simply out of the box. I've just edited my question to show some results and I'd be really thankfull if you could comment on that.

Comment: @fljx Please don't edit solutions into your questions, I've rolled back your edit. If you have a new question, just ask a new question.